# Compress JSON file by eliminating whitespace

Tags: json, whitespace

I am working with a large json file (~100,000 lines) and need to compress it down to make a program run faster. I wish to delete all the horizontal tabs, returns, etc. to minimize the size of the file.

For example if a line was originally:

```
"name_id": "Richard Feynman",
"occupation": "Professional Bongos Player"
```

it should be compressed to:

```
"name_id":"Richard Feynman","occupation":"Professional Bongos Player"`
```

I have scoured the Internet (forgive me if it is a simple answer, I am a beginner) and can't seem to find a command for the terminal that will help me do this. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Google? http://nixtricks.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/sed-replace-a-tab-character-using-sed/

Comment: Yes I tried using sed already, but the majority of the extra data in my file are single spaces. I need a way to differentiate what is in quotes versus what is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a JSON **minifier**.

There are some around, both [online](http://www.httputility.net/json-minifier.aspx) and [standalone](https://github.com/getify/JSON.minify).

Try googling these terms + your favorite language, I'm sure you'll find something that suits your needs.

There are [other tools](https://coderwall.com/p/mekopw) that modify your JSON to make it smaller, but you'll end up with a different JSON, I guess. Haven't tried those.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for RT:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\""} NR%2{gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")} {ORS=RT;print} END{printf "\n"}' file
"name_id":"Richard Feynman","occupation":"Professional Bongos Player"
```

Comment: The code works perfectly for the example I provided, but when I tried using it on the larger file, it didn't do much. Here is what the output was, (original is normal JSON conventions).                                                               children: [{path: /math/arithmetic/, id: arithmetic, title: Arithmetic and pre-algebra, contains: [Topic, Video, Exercises]                                                            it basically just deleted the quotes from all my key-value pairs

Comment: If you have a different example that this solution doesnt work for, update your question to include that example. I have no idea what JSON is or by extension what "normal JSON conventions" means, all I have to go on is the example(s) you provide.

Comment: I would love to have an awk JSON minifier.. unfortunately yours doesn't match JSON standard.. :(

Comment: Of course it doesn't match the JSON standard, it's not supposed to, it's only supposed to help the OP solve his specific stated problem. You don't need a JSON parser to concatenate lines ending in `,` in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The following flex(1) program will do the work.  It makes a lexical analisys of json source and eliminates comments and spaces between tokens, respecting the in-string spaces.  It also recognizes unquoted identifiers, and quotes them.

To compile it, just do

```
make json
```

Use it with the following command:

```
json [ file ... ]
```

if you don't specify a file, the program will read from `stdin`.

Here's the source:

```
%{
/* json-min.  JSON minimizer.
 * Author: Luis Colorado <lc@luiscoloradosistemas.com>
 * Date: Wed Aug 13 07:35:23 EEST 2014
 * Disclaimer: This program is GPL, as of GPL version 3, you
 * may have received a copy of that document, or you can
 * instead look at http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt to read
 * it.  There's no warranty, nor assumed nor implicit on the
 * use of this program, you receive it `as is' so whatever you
 * do with it is only your responsibility.  Luis Colorado
 * won't assume any responsibility of the use or misuse of
 * this program.  You are warned.
 */
%}

dec ([1-9][0-9]*)
oct (0[0-7]*)
hex (0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]*)
doub    ({dec}"."([0-9]*)?|{dec}?"."[0-9]+)
strd    (\"([^\"]|\\.)*\")
t   "true"
f   "false"
n   "null"
com1    "//".*
com2b   "/*"
endc    "*/"
ident   ([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)

%x INCOMMENT
%option noyywrap

%%

{dec}           |
{oct}           |
{hex}           |
{doub}          |
{strd}              |
{t}             |
{f}         |
{n}         |
"{"         |
":"         |
";"         |
"}"         |
"["         |
"]"         |
","         ECHO;

[\ \t\n]        |
{com1}          ;
{com2b}         BEGIN(INCOMMENT);
<INCOMMENT>.        ;
<INCOMMENT>{endc}   BEGIN(INITIAL);

{ident}         { fprintf(stderr, "WARNING:"
                "unquoted identifier %s "
                "in source.  Quoting.\n",
                yytext);
              printf("\"%s\"", yytext);
            }
.           { fprintf(stderr,
                "WARNING: unknown symbol %s "
                "in source, copied to output\n",
                yytext);
              ECHO;
            }

%%

void process(const char *fn);

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int i;
    if (argc > 1) for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        process(argv[i]);
    else process(NULL); /* <-- stdin */
} /* main */

void process(const char *fn)
{
    FILE *f = stdin;
    if (fn) {
        f = fopen(fn, "r");
        if (!f) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR:fopen:%s:%s(errno=%d)\n",
                fn, strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } /* if */
    } /* if */
    yyin = f;
    yylex();
    if (fn) /* only close if we opened, don't close stdin. */
        fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I have just written it, so there's little testing on it.  Use it with care (conserve a backup of your original file)  It doesn't overwrite the original file, just outputs to stdout, so you don't overwrite your data using it.

BR,
Luis

Comment: Just to comment, name the source file `json.l`, and compile it with `make json` or the following: `lex -t json.l > json.c` `cc -o json json.c`